# Use a Xamarin library in native iOS/Android apps

Tags: c#, android, ios, .net, xamarin

We are using xamarin for a while now and developed different apps/libs with it. Now we need to integrate one of the core libraries/component we developed during the last years in native apps. Background: We do a project with a partner who is using native development and we need to integrate our library in his environment/his apps.

So there will be two native apps (iOS/Android) and our core library will be part of them. The question therefore: Is there a way to integrate a xamarin library (or simply C# code, written with xamarin) into the two native apps? Or do we need to completely rewrite the code in Java/Swift?

The library has no third-party libraries except ofc the .NET framework.

Thanks for sharing your experience in this matter!

Comment: You are going to to have to rewrite your library. What you are looking for would be "Embedded Mono" and that is not supported on Xamarin mobile platforms... http://www.mono-project.com/docs/advanced/embedding/

Comment: Maybe this is what are you looking for https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/tools/dotnet-embedding/

Comment: Sadly this seems like it is dead by now :( the link you provided is dead and the last release is 3 years old https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/tools/dotnet-embedding/release-notes/preview/0.4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK there is no way to take a Xamarin .NET library and use it in a native (Java/Obj-C/Swift) platform app.