# Using Xamarin Libraries in Swift or Java android projects

Tags: java, objective-c, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I have been using BIndings library from native objective-c or java, inside my Xamarin Project using bindings libraries.
I just wish to know if it is possible to do the reverse. Make Xamarin Libraries work in java or objective C ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you to use java/objective c library. Xamarin is built based on the platform code, so what you use in forms you can always find in each platforms(ios/android/uwp).

As for your question, I am afraid this can not be done.here is a related question for you to check [Use a Xamarin library in native iOS/Android apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32947306/use-a-xamarin-library-in-native-ios-android-apps)